# MySQL Import - [Large File ~ 350 GB ] - Two weeks and it is still running

Tags: mysql, database, memory-management, ubuntu-14.04, database-administration

I am importing a SQL file into MySQL database. The file is relatively large. It is more than 350 GB. It is almost two weeks and still running. I am running this on a server of 64GB and Ubuntu OS. I have done some troubleshooting and as below:

```
SELECT table_schema "DB Name", Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 
1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"  FROM   information_schema.tables  
GROUP  BY table_schema;
+--------------------+---------------+
| DB Name            | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------+---------------+
| dbx                |      222757.0 |
| information_schema |           0.2 |
| mysql              |           2.4 |
| performance_schema |           0.0 |
| sys                |           0.0 |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

I can see that the dbx size keeps changing which means that the import process is progressing. Also, I have monitored the insertion process using

```
> mysql> show processlist;
  +----+-------+-----------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-------
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Id | User  | Host      | db        | Command | Time | State    | Info                                                                                               

  | 13 | admin | localhost | dbx | Query   |    0 | update   | INSERT INTO 
  `books` VALUES (132304376,4212389,'C Trn,R TYG,Boots','LS, Aziz R. Haya |
```

and it keeps changing within the time, however, it is slow.

I have verified the allocated memory for the database import process and it appears that it uses 2 GB and as follows:

```
 RSS    SZ    VSZ
350520 525497 2101988
```

My questions:

1. The SZ (Physical memory used by SQL import process) is ~ 0.5 GB while my server is 64 GB. Why does this happen? Is there any way to increase the allocated physical memory for the import process?
2. Is it normal to have such amount of time to import the database having a server with 64 GB of memory?
3. Do you recommend any further procedure to investigate this problem giving that I have followed the steps in many stackoveflow threads that discuss similar issues.

Thanks for any help in this regard.

Comment: What's the current value of `SELECT @@INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT;`?

Comment: @Micheal - sqlbot: The result of executing this query is 1

Comment: `SET GLOBAL @@INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT = 2;`.  This will relax the durability of InnoDB transactions by disabling the disk flush after each commit, which protects the server against a lost transaction in the event of a system crash.  It's a resource hog that provides no benefit when all you are doing is restoring a dump file.  This should not disrupt your restore, and should take effect almost immediately.  You should see a notable speed-up.

Comment: I got the following error `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@@INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT = 2' at line 1`

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the two variants of the syntax.  Use either  `SET GLOBAL INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT = 2;` or `SET @@GLOBAL.INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT = 2;` (they are equivalent).

Comment: @Micheal - sqlbot: Thanks ... The command works fine. Does this help in increasing the speed of db import process? Do you recommend doing further actions? Can I access some tables for which the import process has finished? How can we monitor the progress in an efficient way?

Comment: This should help quite a bit.  Any other suggestions I have would require you to restart the server, which would mean starting over on the reload, losing the work done over the last two weeks.  Watching `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is the only way to monitor the reload, now that it is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Probable reason for the import to be so slow is that MySQL updates indices on inserting each record, and index update time increases as table grows. You can experiment with disabling indices before import.

Regading the memory usage - it depends on your server setting: key cache size and etc.

Also you can have a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-diskio.html